# [Mininet/Miniedit]: The hosts cant ping/reach other in a 2 router system

Tags: linux, router, routing, static-routes, routing-table

As a part of an experiment, my network has the following topology for two host machines connected to a router in mininet(on Ubuntu 22.04.02 Virtual Machine)

```
     h1 - r1 - r2 - h2
```

The host Machine 'h1' has the following configuration:

```
h1-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::70e9:dfff:fe2c:6242  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:e9:df:2c:62:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The host Machine 'h2' has the following config:

```
h2-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f429:9fff:fe6a:5211  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:29:9f:6a:52:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The router r1 has the following config:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r1-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::10dc:6cff:feb2:1688  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:dc:6c:b2:16:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r1-eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::8cd5:99ff:fedf:e2a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8e:d5:99:df:e2:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1076 (1.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The router r2 has the following configuration:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r2-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::87d:6aff:fee9:477  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:7d:6a:e9:04:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21  bytes 1398 (1.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

r2-eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::cc40:70ff:fe31:f96d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:40:70:31:f9:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1146 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am trying to setup the experimental topology such that both the hosts can access each other, which of course, is possible through configuring routing tables

I have taken the following steps:

On the **r1 terminal(xterm):**

```shell
    ifconfig r1-eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ifconfig r1-eth1 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev r1-eth0   
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.2
```

On the **r2 terminal(xterm):**

```shell
    ifconfig r2-eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
    ifconfig r2-eth1 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.0  
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.2.1
```

On the **h1 terminal (xterm)**

```shell
    ifconfig h1-eth0 192.168.0.103 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add default gw 192.168.0.1
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
    ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

On the **h2 terminal (xterm)**

```shell
    ifconfig h2-eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
    route add default gw 192.168.1.1
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
    ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

The updated routing tables for h1, h2, r1 and r2 are as follows:

**h1 Routes**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 h1-eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 h1-eth0
192.168.1.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 h1-eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 h1-eth0
```

**h2 routes**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 h2-eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 h2-eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 h2-eth0
```

**r1 route tables**:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r1-eth0
192.168.1.0     192.168.2.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 r1-eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r1-eth1
```

**r2 route tables** :

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 r2-eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r2-eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 r2-eth1
```

When I try pinging h2 from h1 and vice versa I get destination host unreachable error.

where am I going wrong? Is there a step I have skipped? Any insight/help is appreciated.

PS: The following is my ping reachability matrix:

```
*** Ping: testing ping reachability
r1 -> r2 h1 X 
r2 -> r1 X X 
h1 -> r1 r2 X 
h2 -> r1 r2 X
```